# Not able to git push fatal: remote error: Service not enabled

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using gerrit and all other machine works fine.

I just set up a new ubuntu 18 machine and try to upload some changes to the repo, when I do

```
 git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

It gives error

```
fatal: remote error: Service not enabled
fatal: Service not enabled
```

I am able to pull fetch, rebase without any problem,
Does anyone have idea what's going on?

Comment: Please, execute "git remote -v" and show the result.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience it usually means that you don't have permissions to do pushes, or you are not properly authorized.